# Trying to change the text of a label with button

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func cardFlip(_ sender: Any) {
        label.text = "card2" . // this is where I get an error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the "." from the cardFlip method (before the comment).